Integral of $\exp(-bx^2+ax)$
Looking for help on this integral:
$ \int^{+ \infty}_{-\infty} \exp (-bx^2+ax)  dx $
where $b>0$
Integrand being a "displaced" Gaussian, see graph below. Integrands for pos and neg constant $a$, as well as Gaussian for reference. Gaussian (i.e. a=0) has b easily substituted out by $x = \frac{y}{\sqrt{b}} $ solving to $\sqrt \frac{\pi}{b}$ if I'm not mistaken.
I don't see singularity problems, and couldn't be that hard? Dusty integrating skills on my part, I did try for a while to find a substitution.

Side question: Why don't Wolfram Alpha not even recognize the Gaussian case for what it is (i.e. giving $\sqrt \pi$ as answer)? Let alone provide any help with the above integral.

Hint: after dealing with $b$ using your substitution, complete the square

Does this answer your question? Gaussian integral with complex linear component Found using Approach$0$

Completing the square
$-bx^2 + ax = -b(x^2 - 2\frac {a}{2b}x + \frac {a^2}{4b^2}) + \frac {a^2}{4b}\\
-b(x-\frac {a}{2b})^2 + \frac {a^2}{4b}$
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-bx^2 + ax}\ dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-b(x - \frac {a}{2b})^2 + \frac {a^2}{4b}}\ dx\\
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-b(x - \frac {a}{2b})^2}e^{\frac {a^2}{4b}}\ dx\\
e^{\frac {a^2}{4b}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-b(x^2 - \frac {a}{2b})^2}\ dx$
The translation term doesn't affect the integration and can be dropped.
$e^{\frac {a^2}{4b}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-bx^2}\ dx$
$e^{\frac {a^2}{4b}}\sqrt {\frac {\pi}{b}}$

Thx so much. I was already trying to get away from the Gaussian form, find another route or multiple substitutions. Much obliged and admired!

It was (easy to guess that this question is) a duplicate: see comment above.

Yes sorry, I did search the forum, didn't find it
